# Did foursquare venu api change? Can't query specific stores

Tags: geolocation, location, foursquare, google-places-api

I have been querying specific stores from the foursquare venues api like this:

```
 String stores = "";
    try {
        stores = URLEncoder.encode("ULTA Nordstrom Target Costco", "utf8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String placeEndPoint = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=33.859868,-117.886133&query="+stores+"&intent=browse&radius=16093&client_id=clientid&client_secret=secret&v=20130322";
```

For the past 6 months hitting this endpoint has returned a list of the stores above.  However this returns empty now.  If I only input 1 store, I will receive results back, however when I have several like above, nothing returns?

Did something change with the foursquare api?  Is this the proper way to search for multiple specific stores?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if anything changed recently, but instead of making multiple queries in one request, you should be using a [multi](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/multi/multi) request.

The reasoning behind this: these should logically be multiple requests. You wouldn't necessarily conduct a single search for "ULTA Nordstrom Target Costco" (say, on Google) and expect disjoint results for each keyword combined into the one resultset you get back. You'd expect results that relate to *all* the keywords you mentioned. When searching for venues, this severely limits results.

Answer (score 0):

Octopi had a great suggestion and is the route I am going but It did not answer the question.

I believe the answer is yes, the foursquare api did change.